# Using another cell's value as the row number in a reference in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I want to be able to paste a table into a sheet, where then the differences of values between each row is calculated. However, the length of the table is unknown, so I'd like the number of rows of difference calculation to automatically update to the length of the new table inputted.

I am able to use the count function to get the length of the table, but I'm just not sure how I can use the calculated length to then adjust what range of rows the difference will be calculated over.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I agree with the bot; this is confusing.

Comment: Okay, it's been updated to clarify.

Comment: Thanks. This is making more sense. However, it sounds like you want a VBA solution that can analyze the page and adapt to it. There may be a "dumber" solution but I still could you some details. Could you create two dummy tables to illustrate what you mean? That is, may create a table with three rows and demonstrate what you would like to the outcome to be and then a second table with five rows so we can see the differences your are describing.

Comment: Please include a data sample and a formula example.  Many array formulas will adjust as you need.  There's no point us guessing.

Answer (score 0):

`=INDIRECT(...)` will take the argument value (a text / string) and use it as a cell reference or range.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly what you want to achieve, it seems that you are looking for a formula that automatically spills depending on the size of your data. Assuming your values are stored in the range `A1:A6` (see exemplary data below), you could combine `VSTACK()`, `INDEX()`, and `SEQUENCE()` as follows (formula in cell `B2`; output in table below):

```
=VSTACK("",
INDEX(A:A,SEQUENCE(COUNTA(A:A)-2,,2))-
INDEX(A:A,SEQUENCE(COUNTA(A:A)-2,,3)))
```

First, `VSTACK()` is only needed to shift your final result by one row, given that you do not compute the difference for the first value as the value above is "col_a". The first `INDEX()` and `SEQUENCE()` combination is used to obtain all values from the first value to n-th - 1 value, i.e., values 5 to 12 in the table below for `col_a`. The second `INDEX()` and `SEQUENCE()` combination is used to obtain all values from the second value to last value, i.e., values 9 to 4 in the table below for `col_a`.

The `INDEX()` function is pretty straightforward and simply returns the value in the range specified based on the rows/columns specified. Thus, in your case you want to return the values from the range `A:A`. The tricky part in this context is the dynamic nature, because you want to return the rows based on the size of your input data. Thus, we use a `COUNTA()` statement that counts the number of cells that are not empty in the specified range. Based on the data specified below, the `=COUNTA(A:A)` will return a value of 6. This value is used to create a sequence, in particular, specifying the number of rows we want to use in our sequence. Given that we have a header and do not want to include the last (first) row of values respectively, we need to reduce this number by 2. In addition, we want the sequence to start from row 2 (3) to exclude the header and the first value (for the second sequence). Thus, the first `=SEQUENCE(COUNTA(A:A)-2,,2)` statement will return the following array `{2;3;4;5}`. These are exactly the rows that we want to return in the `INDEX()` statement.

Combining these statements will lead you to difference between consecutive rows specified in the table below as `diff_a`. For the first case, it will be `5-9 = -4` and so on.

If you now add/remove datapoints in column A, the formula stored in cell `B2` will automatically spill to the respective array of your data. Note, this assumes that column A has only the values that you really use for your computation. If the column includes below additional values or tables, it will mess-up the computation of the `COUNTA()` function.

*Data and Result:*

| col_a | diff_a |
| --- | --- |
| 5 |  |
| 9 | -4 |
| 10 | -1 |
| 12 | -2 |
| 4 | 8 |